# Is there a way to prevent Node.js app from crashing on error in async fuction?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, error-handling

Consider we are using following module:

```js
//buggy-module.js
function asyncFunctionThatCrashes() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let a = bibi.tibi; // Error
      resolve('super');
    }, 500);
  });
}
module.exports = asyncFunctionThatCrashes;
```

in our project:

```js
//our-project.js
const asyncFunctionThatCrashes = require('buggy-module');

router.get('/',
  async (req, res) => {
    try{
       const result = await asyncFunctionThatCrashes();
       res.status(200).send(result);
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).send(); // this will not happen
    }
 })
```

In this case application crashes (`try...catch` doesn't help, since the error occurs in async function).
Is there a way to prevent crashing?

Comment: You have to catch the exception inside that asynchronous callback with try/catch.  If you convert all your logic and control flow to use promises, then it's a lot easier to propagate errors that occur in asynchronous code that are promise-based.

Comment: @jfriend00 so if I use some external package with a bug (unhandled error) it will cause to app crash, and there is no way to prevent it?...

Comment: You can't fix junk code from the outside.  You can register a handler for the [`uncaughtException` event](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception), but at that point, it's too late to actually "fix" the error.